# Getting wrong date in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, date

I tried all the solutions i found here but none work.
Im just trying:

```
var a = new Date();
console.log(a);
//2020-01-12T05:05:17.320Z

//Time in my timezone: 2020-01-12T02:05:17.320Z
```

I'm from Brazil, o the timezone is -3:00

I already installed moment.js and tryed:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format();

var a = new Date();
console.log(a);
```

but i keep getting whithout my timezone. I also tryed setting the TZ without the moment.js and didn't work.

I cant use some solution that change the way to call the "new Date()" because I have to parse a string to an object that contains Date and I use Prompts module, that get a date from console, that already return a date. I don't know what to do more.

Thanks for any help.

*I'm running on Windows, and the time is right, the configuration is pointing to the right timezone

edit1: more info

Comment: Try `moment(a).tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format()`

Comment: When you say 'real' time, can you explicitly state if you mean 'the current time on my local clock', or 'the current time in UTC'. It's not clear. If you can, update your question for clarity. This is important because you're probably seeing the right time, but probably not in the timezone you're expecting

Comment: Very likely the "real" time is actually 2020-01-12T02:05:17.320-03:00, which is the same moment in time as 2020-01-12T05:05:17.320Z but with a different offset.

Comment: where do you run your node.js app? docker or the same laptop that you got `real time: 2020-01-12T02:05:17.320Z`?

Comment: @Evert ok, i've just changed, i'm getting the time without my timezone

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon i'm running on my laptop, and it shows the right time, with the timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I found was add 'getTimezoneOffset' (minutes) using moment.js

```
//Will returns the current "wrong" time in formart '2020-09-29T19:47:46.411Z'
//Expect: 2020-09-29T16:47:46.411Z
console.log(new Date())
```

So if you want see the full date in format ('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm') of any object

```
var moment = require('moment')
// specificDay is a Date (type: Object) like '2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z' 
// previously retrieved from the database without information about the time('HH:mm')
// Only with 'YYYY-MM-DD'
moment(specificDay, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),'minute').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Moment is a Javascript library that makes formatting time very easy. You are creating your moment object, but you're not outputting it.

I made a very slight change (2nd line) and it works as expected:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
console.log(moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format());
```

If you want it formatted nicely, see this page: https://momentjs.com/.

For example:

```
console.log(moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format('lll'));
// output: Jan 12, 2020 2:45 AM
```

How does it work?

`moment()` creates a time object (just like `new Date()`, but it's moment's special time object). `.tz()` is calling the timezone function and we give it your time zone as a string "America/Sao_Paulo". `.format()` then outputs it in a nice custom string. `console.log()` outputs the whole string to the screen.

Comment: Please explain the "slight change" that you made. As far as I can tell, the only difference is including *console.log*, there is no meaningful change to the actual expression.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the change I made. The author of the question was printing out the vanilla Javascript `Date` object. Instead, they should have logged the moment.js Date object.

Comment: The change of console.log outputs the right date and time, but after that, when I parse an object that contains date it continues wrong

Comment: Make sure you are using `moment.js`'s Date object. Do not accidentally use Javascripts `Date()` object. If you want to do more operations with your local Brazil date object, do something like: `var myDate = moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo");` followed by your operations eg: `console.log(myDate.format('lll'));`

Answer (score 1):

Node takes UTC timestamp
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=current+utc+time+online

So you can convert to a locale string and after that create a new date. This is a example for mexico city

```
let mx = (new Date()).toLocaleString('se-SE',{ timeZone: 'America/Mexico_City'}) + "Z";
return new Date(mx);
```